# angular 2 router remainder path

Tags: angular, router

How can I match a route like this:

```
/github/my-project/and/a/long/path
```

I am looking for:

```
/github/:repo/**  

 {
    path: 'github/:repo/*',
    component: Page,
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {
    path: 'github/:repo/**',
    component: Page,
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
 },
```

or

```
 {
    path: 'github/:repo',
    component: Page,
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    children: { path: '**' component: SomeComponent }
 },
```